# How do you create a dynamic SharePoint Web Part

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to create a Web Part for Share Point in C# which displays images in a slide show style sliding from right to left. I know there are Web Parts you can download but i need to write my own. I need to know how to either draw to some graphics context or have a way of updating an image using a timer and changing its ImageURL. This is among several Web Parts I will be making so the question does not simply apply to sliding images but drawing in general. Thanks

Comment: Just use the editor web part and use some JS

Comment: The point is that i have to use c# to get marks in a project

Comment: Have you tried anything or what do you want from us exactly?

Comment: im trying to use the Update Panel and postback the image area to change the image every so often, this seems to work for changing the image, but what if i wanted to slide the image in from the left do i have to write client side code?